# Python in terminal- Trying to use ''erase'' and it writes more

Tags: command-line, python

im really new to both Ubuntu and trying to learn to use python.
Ive just installed python. When i start python in terminal "python3.5" my keys are adding more when i try to erase text. When i try to hit erase it will write (^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^).
Do you guys have any ide what the source of this problem is? 
Terminal will let me erase if i dont load python.

[image]